# PhoneGap notification (Push)

Tags: ios, cordova, push

I want to send a notification to my app users, if they not used the app before 12.00 they should get a message ("You should start the app... bla bla bla") - iOS

And if the users has start the app before 12.00 they should not get any message.

Do i have to use server push och can i use local push?

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

You could use either...but local notifications is going to be a bit hacky. Ideally, you'll want to use APNS via your own server, which will let you keep track of exactly when users have run your app and alert accordingly.

Of course, you're also going to need to build a system to handle this, and send data from the app back to you server to record and process. This is relatively straightforward, but if you've not done any back-end server work before you may find it difficult.

I suppose you could use local notifications by scheduling notifications for 12PM for the next X number of days, and cancelling notifications on a per-day basis if the user opens up the app before midday. But this isn't ideal either.

Personally, I'm not sure I'd enjoy using an app that constantly reminded me to use it, but that's just my opinion!